# My theme is falling back to default theme in my package

Tags: magento, themes

I have installed a magento website and configured one store.In configuration design i added the package and theme i have created for it in website level, store level as well as default store level

folder structure is like

packagename/default

packagename/mytheme

I have added catalog.xml to packagename/mytheme/layout folder to remove some of my right side elements like compare products.since it was not working i tried it with local.xml also

but it falls back to packagename/default/layout/catalog.xml

Can anybody give some idea what am i doing wrong

Thanks
I remain

Comment: can you add a screen capture of your design config in BO and your design/ directory structures ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `System > Configuration > GENERAL > Design > Themes > Layout`, it should be "default"
and check `System > Configuration > GENERAL > Design > Package >  Current Package Name` it should be "packagename".

If these settings are correct, delete the cache as .suggested by Cags and everything should work fine

Answer (score 0):

I find that normally, if you changed something in xml and it's not working, it's because of cache. My preferred option for purging the cache is with `rm -rf var/cache/mage--*`.

Comment: its not because of the cache. i have already disabled the cache